# Javascript JSON string to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

When I query a database, I receive a string as follows:

```
{
  S: '[{"firstName":"Max","lastName":"Mustermann","age":40},{"firstName":"Hagbard","lastName":"Celine","age":44},{"firstName":"Karl","lastName":"Koch","age":42}]'
}
```

How can I go about converting the string above to JSON objects to receive something like this:

```
var someData = [
  {firstName: "Max", lastName: "Mustermann", age: 40},
  {firstName: "Hagbard", lastName: "Celine", age: 44},
  {firstName: "Karl", lastName: "Koch", age: 42},
];
```

Would appreciate any assistance at all, thank you very much!

Comment: have you tried `someData = JSON.parse(someObj.s)`?

Comment: you can use `JSON.parse(yourdata)`

Comment: Hi, when I use that I get `Error [SyntaxError]: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: First JSON.stringify(someData) and then parse it. Seems like you're already passing a string version of a JSON object

Comment: @Halmon Yes, I wanted to convert that string version back to a JSON object but seem to be getting `Error [SyntaxError]: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` while using `JSON.parse(yourdata)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const receivedFromDB = {
  S: '[{"firstName":"Max","lastName":"Mustermann","age":40},{"firstName":"Hagbard","lastName":"Celine","age":44},{"firstName":"Karl","lastName":"Koch","age":42}]'
};

const arrayOfData = JSON.parse(receivedFromDB.S);

console.log(arrayOfData);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfect, I was missing the '.S'. I am waiting to accept your answer in 2 mins time :)